# File Corruption

Tags: windows

I have a laptop with two SSDs running in RAID 0 stripping mode. Operating System is Windows 10. I have two partitions on the drive with drive letters C: and D:, where C: has the software installed and D: is for data. Filesystem is NTFS. A quite typical setup.

The problem I am facing is that the large files (i.e. more than 20MB) in D: get corrupted. And it doesn't require any read or write operations to corrupt the files. For example when I open a large CSV data file I find that some lines are missing, or some lines are half deleted.

I get no errors from the O/S. CHKDSK reveals no problems. The most worrying part is that there is no indication that something bad happened to the file. When I make backups the backups simply copy the corrupted files, making backup process useless. The files copy without any error messages (i.e. read error or checksum). File is there but the data in it dissappears. It is very insidious. I end up destroying my good backups by overwriting them with a corrupted version.

I would say this is an SSD problem, but why is it happening only on partition D:? It is the same RAID stack and if there is a problem I assume it should affect the entire disk, especially in a RAID 0 stripping situation.

What kind of problem am I looking at, how can I diagnose the problem?

Comment: Have you tested the disks independently? Can they store data up to their capacity correctly? Does the file size remain correct, but the content is incorrect?

Comment: "_NTFS has no checksum on data so there is actually no way to figure out silent data corruption._" correct.

Comment: How is RAID implemented? By hardware / [Intel RST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Matrix_RAID) / [Windows Dynamic Disks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager)?

Comment: @Attie I don't know the details. It is definitely not hardware. It is software raid. When I inspect the properties it seems it is based in Intel Rapid Storage technology that came default with windows 10 installation.

Comment: This is an odd one... are you sure that _only_ larger files are being affected? (bear in mind that smaller files have a smaller vulnerable surface). What are the disks? (Manufacturer & Model)

Comment: @Attie You are right. Maybe small files are affected but so far I can only observe in my very large text files as they are much more vulnerable and I have a parsing process for these file where I can detect the errors (parsing fails due to not finding required number of columns in a row for example because they dissappeared). I will check the model of SSDs when I get back home. The laptop is Asus Zenbook, and disks are whatever came with the unit. I haven't modified or tampered with anything.

Comment: Can you confirm that it's not your application at fault? Do you only see the issue with your "_large text files_"? What about videos / photos?

Comment: @Attie For sure it is not the application. A lot of videos and PDF files got corrupted as well.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1363178/edit) and add all this extra detail... we can then remove our comments. Unfortunately I don't think I can help you here...